# Properly cite a document from the WHO assembly

Tags: citations, writing

I want to cite a document from this years WHO [World Health Assembly](http://www.who.int/world-health-assembly/seventy-first). The document in question can be found by clicking on ["Main Documents"](http://apps.who.int/gb/e/e_wha71.html) on their page and then selecting the document with the title [A71/21 (Improving access to assistive technology)](http://apps.who.int/gb/ebwha/pdf_files/WHA71/A71_21-en.pdf).

I like to use IEEE referencing, so I would do it like this:

World Health Organization (WHO). 2018.
Improving access to assistive technology (A71/21).
Seventy-first World Health Assembly, World Health Organization, Geneva.
Available: http://apps.who.int/gb/ebwha/pdf_files/WHA71/A71_21-en.pdf. [Accessed: 03-Dec-2018]

Is this acceptable?

Thanks!

Comment: Given the a71/21, year and agency (WHO) seem sufficient. Check the publishing agency,if applicable, for instructions on how to cite report agency reports.